# How to Validate a GET method Form using Mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to check whether the UDISE code already exist or not through mysql database...My Code looks like this...
How could i validate this field? pls help

```
<?php 
  include('logprocess.php') ?>
     <html>
    <head>
      <title>Login Form </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <form action="regnew.php" method="GET" id="register_form">
        <h1>---- </br>
        <br> 
        LOGIN</br></h1>


       <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your UDISE Code "maxlength="11"  id="udise"  name="udise">
        </div>

        <br>
        <div>
        <button type="submit"  name="register"  id="reg_btn">Enter</button>
        </div>
        </br>
    <span class="footer"></span>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My Php code is as follows .. i have saved it as different file and i used include option to call the file. But nothing is working

```
<?php

  // Grab User submitted information

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
// Make sure we connected successfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
 $udise = "";
// Select the database to use
$db = mysql_select_db("workspace",$con);
  if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
$sql_udise = "SELECT * FROM udise WHERE schcd='$udise'" or die (mysql_error());
$res_udise = mysqli_query($db, $sql_udise) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_udise);
    $fields = array( 'udise');
$error = false; //No errors yet
foreach($fields AS $fieldname) { //Loop trough each field
  if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    alert("Pls Enter All Fields");
    </script>';  //Display error with field
    $error = true; //Yup there are errors
  }
}
if(!$error) {
    if($row["udise"]==$udise ){
   echo '<script language="javascript">
  top.location.href = "updatewp.php"; //the page to redirect
    </script>';
}else {
   echo '<script language="javascript">
    alert("Sorry... UDISE Mismatch pls try again ");
     href = "login.php"; //the page to redirect
    </script>';}

{
   echo '<script language="javascript">
         href = "login.php"; //the page to redirect
    </script>';
}

    mysql_close($con);
}}
?>
```

how could i add this to login form validation

Comment: We need to see your PHP code, friend.

Comment: You do not have any php code to show?

Comment: Sir..I have attached the Php Code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<html><head><title>Login Form </title><link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css"></head><body></body><form method="GET" id="register_form"><h1>---- </br><br> LOGIN</br</h1><div>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your UDISE Code "maxlength="11"  id="udise"  name="udise">
</div>

<br>
<div>
<button type="submit"  name="register"  id="reg_btn">Enter</button>
</div>
</br><span class="footer"></span></form><?php if(isset($_GET['register'])){$udise = $_GET['udise'];
 //connect to the database  $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'yourdb';

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 
$check=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from udise where udise='$udise'");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check); if($checkrows>0) {
  echo '<div style="color: #a94442;
background-color: #f2dede;
border-color: #ebccd1;padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;">
 already exist </div>'; } else {  
//insert results from the form input
  $query = "INSERT INTO udise(udise) VALUES('$udise')";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

  mysqli_close($conn);

  echo '<div style="color: #3c763d;
background-color: #dff0d8;
border-color: #d6e9c6;padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;">
 POSTED </div>' ;
}}?>  </body> </html>
```

Comment: Sir.. Thanks for your immediate reply.. I used your code.. but it does not show any alert.. it allows both correct and incorrect values

Comment: Its a GET method form.. After Correct Udise Code Entry it should execute the code to a new form ( with some field values from udise table).. from that form only insert query should run

Comment: Login to Updation page

Comment: Sorry Goutham, I don't understand exactly what you told. You asked, "I want to check whether the UDISE code already exist or not through mysql database" so thats why i gave that code.

Comment: You want alert use this echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("This is alert")';
echo '</script>'; and you want updation, you can change else part redirect page or just give updation query.

Comment: Let me clarify sir.. What i need is.. When user enter udise code it should verify the udise code with the database .. If the Udise Code is correct the value will be passed to next form .. that form will have field value corresponding to udise code.. like school name, address.. and the user has to input some other values in the form and submit to insert it to a table.. Everything worked fine for me.. but first login form whether udise code correct or not cannot be checked.. if he enter wrong code it shows blank field .. rather showing error.. pls help if possible.. thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php session_start();
//Your Mysql Config
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "yourdb";

//Create New Database Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check Connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection Failed: ". $conn->connect_error);

}



if(isset($_GET['login']))
{




    $sql = "SELECT * FROM udise WHERE udise='".$_GET['udise']."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $extra="profile.php";
    $_SESSION['login']=$_GET['udise'];
    $_SESSION['id']=$num['id'];
    echo "<script>window.location.href='".$extra."'</script>";
    exit();
    }
    } else {
    $_SESSION['action1']="*Invalid usercode";
    $extra="log.php";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='".$extra."'</script>";
    exit();
     }
    $conn->close();

    }

    ?>

    <form method="GET">

     <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your UDISE Code "maxlength="11"  id="udise"  name="udise">



                                     <p style="color:#F00; padding-top:20px;" align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['action1'];?><?php echo $_SESSION['action1']="";?></p>


                        <input class="small button search-btn" type="submit" value="Log In" name="login">
                        </form>
```

Comment: sir thanks for your perseverance.. the code is working for incorrect udise code but with correct udise code it go to the proper page but it show undefined index udise error ..( I think the input udise code not passed to the page) pls go through..

Comment: $_SESSION['id']=$num['id']; Sir this line shows undefined variable

Comment: just remove that line

Comment: I have removed it .. still it shows undefined index (udise) error in new page.. i couldn't correct the error

Comment: did you receive error in login page or profile page?

Comment: in profile page only sir.. There I used $id=$_GET['udise'] code

Comment: <?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['login'];

?>

Comment: $id = $_SESSION['login'];

Comment: Exactly sir.. you are great.. It worked like a charm... hats off to you....